# Switch textboxes to enter automatically after time

Tags: vb.net

So I am making this sort of clock thing and I find it hard to discover a way to switch from textbox to another textbox every second. I've tried timers and dispatchtimer but I didn't succeed so I am looking for some expert tips.
The code below works.

Here's my vb.net script:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    AddHandler TextBox1.Enter, AddressOf TextBox1_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox2.Enter, AddressOf TextBox2_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox3.Enter, AddressOf TextBox3_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox4.Enter, AddressOf TextBox4_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox5.Enter, AddressOf TextBox5_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox6.Enter, AddressOf TextBox6_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox7.Enter, AddressOf TextBox7_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox8.Enter, AddressOf TextBox8_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox9.Enter, AddressOf TextBox9_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox10.Enter, AddressOf TextBox10_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox11.Enter, AddressOf TextBox11_Enter
    AddHandler TextBox12.Enter, AddressOf TextBox12_Enter


End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.Blue
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox3_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox4_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.Green
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox5_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.Pink
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox6_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.Teal
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox7_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.SteelBlue
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox8_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.LightGray
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox9_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.Gold
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox10_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox11_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.Orange
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox12_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BackColor = Color.Brown
End Sub
End Class
```

I am also posting a design of a clock for better imagination of the idea.
[image]

Comment: Put the `TextBoxes` in an array and store the index of the current `TextBox` in a field. Use a `Timer` and, on each `Tick`, increment the index, get the array element at the new index and call its `Select` method to focus it.  Obviously, once the index goes past the end of the array, you need to wrap back to zero.

Comment: Why do you have all those `AddHandler` statements instead of using `Handles` clauses on your methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i'm no professional (which will be evident by the long way i've come up with a solution, i'm sure someone who does it for a living could get it done much more eloquently) but here's what i came up with as it seemed like a fun task.

I've got it stating a timer on launch, then when the button is clicked a new thread is started in the background, that new thread increments a counter every second, and timer1_tick is constantly checking what the counter value is and adjusting the form and textboxes accordingly, it's changing the colour, putting the number in and making it the focused item.

You'll need the following items on Form1: 
Textboxes 1 to 12 (in the pattern you provided with 12 being the top one)
A button (Button1)
Drag a timer (Timer1) onto Form1

Then replace the code on Form1 with the below

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
Dim WorkerThread As New Thread(AddressOf DoWork)
Public StartStop As Boolean
Dim Counter As Integer

Private Sub DoWork()
    StartStop = False
    Do Until StartStop = True
        Counter = 0
        Do Until Counter = 13
            Counter = Counter + 1
            Application.DoEvents()
            If Counter < 13 Then Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Loop
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WorkerThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ClearAllTBs()
    If Counter = 1 Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Bisque
        TextBox1.Text = "1"
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 2 Then
        TextBox2.BackColor = Color.Beige
        TextBox2.Text = "2"
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 3 Then
        TextBox3.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
        TextBox3.Text = "3"
        TextBox3.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 4 Then
        TextBox4.BackColor = Color.Crimson
        TextBox4.Text = "4"
        TextBox4.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 5 Then
        TextBox5.BackColor = Color.DarkCyan
        TextBox5.Text = "5"
        TextBox5.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 6 Then
        TextBox6.BackColor = Color.DarkMagenta
        TextBox6.Text = "6"
        TextBox6.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 7 Then
        TextBox7.BackColor = Color.Gold
        TextBox7.Text = "7"
        TextBox7.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 8 Then
        TextBox8.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia
        TextBox8.Text = "8"
        TextBox8.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 9 Then
        TextBox9.BackColor = Color.DarkViolet
        TextBox9.Text = "9"
        TextBox9.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 10 Then
        TextBox10.BackColor = Color.MediumSeaGreen
        TextBox10.Text = "10"
        TextBox10.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 11 Then
        TextBox11.BackColor = Color.Navy
        TextBox11.Text = "11"
        TextBox11.Focus()
    End If
    If Counter = 12 Then
        TextBox12.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
        TextBox12.Text = "12"
        TextBox12.Focus()
    End If
    Application.DoEvents()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
    StartStop = True
    WorkerThread.Abort()
End Sub

Private Sub ClearAllTBs()
    TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox2.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox3.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox4.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox5.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox6.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox7.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox8.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox9.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox10.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox11.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox12.BackColor = Color.White
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    TextBox5.Text = ""
    TextBox6.Text = ""
    TextBox7.Text = ""
    TextBox8.Text = ""
    TextBox9.Text = ""
    TextBox10.Text = ""
    TextBox11.Text = ""
    TextBox12.Text = ""
End Sub
End Class
```